# How can I access UNC paths using the Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have downloaded BASH for Windows 10. How would I navigate to a network address as I would in a Windows environment? I have seen SAMBA mentioned and have downloaded **smbclient**.

I have tried:

```
smbclient \\localhost\
```

I receive the error

```
ERROR: Could not determine network interfaces, you must use a interfaces config file
```

I am a novice user of BASH, and see this as an opportunity to be more efficient.

As a bonus please show how I could accomplish some common tasks such as copying files across a network, as well as how to authenticate since this would likely be required for such operations.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the latest Windows release "Fall Creators Update" [it is possible to mount UNC paths, or any other filesystem that Windows can access, from within WSL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2017/04/18/file-system-improvements-to-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/).

You can do this with the `mount` command as usual, with the filesystem "`drvfs`" provided by WSL:

```
sudo mount -t drvfs '\\server\share' /mnt/share
```

Single quotes are useful around the UNC path so that you don't have to escape the backslashes. You can mount on an arbitrary directory; I've used `/mnt/share` as an example here, but any empty directory will do.

All files will show up with full `a+rwx` `777` permissions. The real access rights will be checked when you try to access a file, and you can get an error at that point even if it looks like the operation should succeed. Every readable file will be treated as executable.

---

For locations that require credentials you have three options:

1. Prior to mounting, navigate to the location using Windows' File Explorer and authenticate. WSL will inherit your credentials and permissions. This is the easiest way for a one-off.
2. Use the `net use` command from a cmd prompt, or `net.exe use` from inside WSL (`cd /mnt/c` first to suppress a warning). You'll need something like `net.exe use \\server\share <PASSWORD> /USER:<USERNAME>`. You can use `'*'` for the password to be prompted instead. Other configurations are shown with `net.exe help use`.
3. Use the Windows Credential Manager to set up a stored credential. I've never done this one.

---

I understand that Samba proper can be made to work under WSL as well, but since the host provides the same functionality I would use the built-in version from Windows when it's available. `smbclient` is primarily for FTP-style access to SMB servers and retrieving/putting individual files, and it should work when appropriately configured as usual.

Answer (score -2):

This is automatically done on WSL2. On PC running WSL2:

```
\\wsl$
```

Comment: This is the reverse of what the question is asking for (accessing the WSL files via a UNC path, rather than accessing a UNC path from WSL).

Comment: Lol you are literally on the same computer! Minimize the WSL, navigate to \\wsl$, and copy files to or from windows to WSL!  Zero effort. But if you read the question carefully they don't actual say what direction.  UNC is just a network path and doesn't imply WSL, or Windows, or any other OS/app. I'm actually rather surprised no one is finding my solution helpful since it's built-in exactly for this purpose.

Comment: While on Windows itself (even on the terminal) you can seamlessly use UNC paths and work inside them, this is not possible inside a WSL container (i.e., `cd \\myserver\myshare` will not work), unless the UNC path is mounted. Your solution is a answer to the question "how can I access files of the WSL containers from windows" not "how can I access a UNC path from *within* a WSL container"